# Postgresql: Fin inesperado de la definición de la función al final de la entrada

Tags: postgresql

espero puedan ayudarme, quiero hacer una consulta sql utilizando variables, y estoy utilizando la siguiente forma:

declaro mi variable llamada asesor con un valor de 2 y la ocupo dentro del where como parámetro de "idAdvisor_id"

```
do $$
declare asesor int := 2;
begin
SELECT *FROM public."AsesorSch_aevento"
WHERE ("idAdvisor_id"=asesor)AND ("startEvent" BETWEEN '2020-10-26 00:00:00' AND '2020-10-26 23:59:59')
ORDER BY inicio
end $$;
```

pero me muestra el siguiente error:

fin inesperado de la definición de la función al final de la entrada

¿Que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza [EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-execute.html) para hacer las consultas dinámicas por ejemplo:

```
DO $$
DECLARE asesor int := 2;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE '''SELECT * FROM public.\"AsesorSch_aevento\" WHERE (\"idAdvisor_id\" = ' ||asesor || ') AND (\"startEvent\" BETWEEN ''2020-10-26 00:00:00'' AND ''2020-10-26 23:59:59'') ORDER BY inicio''';
END $$;
```

Comment: Hola, esto no resolvió el problema, me muestra el siguiente error:

ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «'SELECT * FROM public.\"AsesorSch_aevento\" WHERE (\"idAdvisor_id\" = 2) AND (\"startEvent\" BETWEEN '»
LINE 1: 'SELECT * FROM public.\"AsesorSch_aevento\" WHERE (\"idAdvis...
        ^
QUERY:  'SELECT * FROM public.\"AsesorSch_aevento\" WHERE (\"idAdvisor_id\" = 2) AND (\"startEvent\" BETWEEN '2020-10-26 00:00:00' AND '2020-10-26 23:59:59') ORDER BY inicio'
CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL inline_code_block en la línea 4 en EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601